Accessing images on the android device to set as a profile picture in kivy
As i have not yet built the APK file I'm working in laptop so i have provided the d drive path, but what should i provide if i want to access the images in the android
def open_camera(self):
   file_chooser1 = FileChooserListView(path=r'D:\mbl photos',)  
   file_chooser1.bind(on_submit=self.selected_file)
   # Create and open a Popup containing the file chooser
   self.popup = Popup(title='Select a file', content=file_chooser1,  size=(0.9,0.9),)
   self.popup.open()

